# Moving route from Rails Application to Rails Engine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I'm working on a project where I have a Rails application (rails 4.2.5) that incorporates a gem, which is a Rails Engine. I'm currently working on moving the route definitions from the main application to the gem. I have a controller test that exercises one of the routes. The test fails when I move the route definition over to the gem, but the route looks the same.

My gem is called CallCenter, and includes a controller called call_center_controller (with an action called reports_tab). This is what routes.rb looks like in the Rails app:

```
...
mount CallCenter::Engine, at: "/call_center", as: 'call_center_urls'
get '/call_center/reports_tab'    => 'call_center/call_center#reports_tab'
...
```

This is what I get running rake routes:

```
❯❯❯ rake routes | grep reports_tab
            call_center_reports_tab GET      /call_center/reports_tab(.:format)                                            call_center/call_center#reports_tab
```

At this point controller test runs without errors. But when I move the route definition to the routes.rb file in the gem:

```
  get 'call_center/reports_tab'    => 'call_center#reports_tab'
```

(note that the route now points to 'call_center#reports_tab' instead of 'call_center/call_center#reports_tab', because the main application mounts the engine at /call_center)

Here is my output from rake routes, (still running from the main app's directory)

```
❯❯❯ rake routes | grep reports_tab
               call_center_reports_tab GET   /call_center/reports_tab(.:format)         call_center/call_center#reports_tab
```

This is identical to the route reported by rake routes when it was defined in the main app, but now my test fails with the following message:

```
     Failure/Error: get :reports_tab

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"reports_tab", :controller=>"call_center/call_center"}
```

As far as I can tell the route is defined, and looks exactly the same as it did before when it was in the routes file for the main app. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - I needed to add this to my controller spec to tell it to look at the routes provided by the Engine:

```
routes { CallCenter::Engine.routes }
```